# Intercepting data sent by input device

Tags: linux, node.js, bash, stream, usb

I'm trying to log any input data that comes from a piano connected to computer via usb.

```
$ lsusb
... 
Bus 003 Device 046: ID fc08:0101  
....
```

`Bus 003 Device 046: ID fc08:0101` is my piano.

If I do `$ cat /dev/bus/usb/003/046` I get something strange:

```
�P   e�2   $   $A$$ $ $ �%   %
```

Also,  I wrote a little NodeJS script that should create a read stream and log data:

```
var Fs = require("fs");

var str = Fs.createReadStream("/dev/bus/usb/003/046");
str.on("data", function (chunk) {
    console.log("data: " + chunk.toString());
});

str.on("error", function (chunk) {
    console.log("error" + chunk.toString());
});

str.on("end", function (chunk) {
    console.log("ended");
});
```

Output:

```
$ node read.js 
data: �P e�2   $   $A$$ $ $ �%   %
ended
```

Why is the stream ending? How can I capture data coming from piano?

Is it possible to parse data and log the piano key that I pressed?

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I'm recommendig to you using `perl`. Read the next module description Device::USB(https://metacpan.org/pod/Device::USB) and you will get the full `libusb` library to an scripting language. IMHO - handy.

Comment: @jm666 Can you add an answer with an example?

Comment: I think `/dev/bus/usb/003/046` is not a character device in which you can just `cat` and endlessly read input from it.

Comment: @konsolebox But what's the character device? It's the first time when I'm trying to do this...

Comment: Unfortunately no, because i'm on OS X and have problems to install the module. (should be no problem on Linux). But you can check many examples in MetaCPAN, e.g. controlling toy-usb rocket lanuncher with the Device::USB and such. Give yourself some time and search matecapn for "Device::USB" & read... (like: https://metacpan.org/pod/Device::USB::MissileLauncher)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `/dev/input/by-id/[Your piano]`

For example, my mouse is at `/dev/input/by-id/usb-Microsoft_Microsoft_5-Button_Mouse_with_IntelliEye_TM_-event-mouse`

Comment: Then only file that I have there is `usb-Chicony_Electronics_Co._Ltd._USB2.0_HD_UVC_WebCam_0x0001-event-if00` that seems to be my webcam.

Comment: Hmm, can you find it using `cat /proc/bus/input/devices`?

Comment: Then I got no idea mate, all my connected usb devices are listed there.